# Multiply char with float

Tags: programming

I have a value for led brightness that is stored as an `unsigned char` (0-255)

```
unsigned char* colors[3];
colors[0] = 255;
colors[1] = 0;
colors[2] = 0;
```

I want to multiply a brightness percentage to that value.

```
float percent = 0.5;
auto red_brightness = colors[0] * percent
```

Since `colors[0]` is of type `char` and `percent` is of type `float`. It gives error `Invalid operands of types 'unsigned char*' and 'float' to binary 'operator*'`

```cpp
unsigned char brightness;
float percent;
unsigned char* colors[3];

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  colors[0] = 255;
  colors[1] = 0;
  colors[2] = 0;
}

void loop() {
    brightness = 127;
    float percent = (float)brightness / 255;
    float newRed = (float)colors[0] * percent;
    
    Serial.println(percent);
    Serial.print("red ");
    Serial.print(newRed);
    Serial.println("");
    delay(1000);
}
```

How can I multiply `colors[0]` (255) by `0.5` to get `127`?

---

### What I've tried

1. Cast `colors[0]` to a float or int

```
    # invalid cast from type 'unsigned char' to type 'float'

    float newRed = (float)colors[0] * percent;
```

2. strtod

Using [this conversion website](https://www.convertdatatypes.com/Convert-char-Array-to-float-in-CPlusPlus.html), I've tried converting like so:

```
    float tempColor = (float)strtod(colors[0],NULL);
    float newRed = tempColor * percent;
```

While this compiles, it always returns `0` (not `127` like I expect)

```cpp
unsigned char brightness;
float percent;
unsigned char* colors[3];

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  colors[0] = 255;
}

void loop() {
    brightness = 127;
    float percent = (float)brightness / 255;
    float tempColor = (float)strtod(colors[0],NULL); // <- returns 0.00

    Serial.print("tempColor");
    Serial.println(tempColor);
    delay(1000);
}
```

How can I multiply `255` by `0.5` to get `~127` ?

---

### Solution

Thanks to the pointer by st2000 and [this sparkfun article on datatypes](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/data-types-in-arduino/defining-data-types)

I avoided floating point and char arrays and converted everything to `byte` and now my code works as expected. Thank you

```
byte brightness;
byte percent;
byte colors[3];

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  colors[0] = 255;
}
void loop() {
      percent = 50;
      auto foobar = colors[0] * percent / 100;
      Serial.print("foobar: ");
      Serial.println(foobar);
```

```
11:12:19.833 -> foobar: 127
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using "floats" is expensive both in required space and execution time.  Consider avoiding the problem entirely and use [uint8_t or byte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10457210/arduino-uint8-t-variables) for everything.

Then just assume

```
percent = 50;
```

... is 50%.  Then try:

```
tempColor =  colors[0] * percent / 100;
```

... where all variables are of type uint8_t or byte.

Comment: @spuder, please follow  up to let us know if the above code suggestion works.  I think C uses type int for intermediate values in which case the worst expected case (255*100) should not exceed the limits of a type int variable.  Otherwise casting one of the variables to a type uint16_t would likely make the code more portable / less likely to break.

Answer (score 4):

You wrote:

> I have an led brightness that is stored as an `unsigned char` (0-255)
>
> ```cpp
> unsigned char* colors[3];
> ```

This is not an array of `unsigned char`, this is an array of
**pointers** to `unsigned char`. If you instead write

```cpp
unsigned char colors[3];
```

Everything should work as expected.

But then, st2000 has very good advice on how to avoid expensive floating
point operations.

Comment: Oooo, good catch @edgar!